# How to get the same result from aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012

Like:

| name | metric |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| a | 1 |

```
SELECT SUM(metric), name 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY name
```

Is there a way that I can get the **same** `name` every time I run this? How does SQL Server choose `a` or `A` to present?

Comment: The names are considered equivalent given the current collation. Therefore both results are "the same". If they weren't considered equivalent (e.g. in a case sensitive collation) they'd be in different groups.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2005? 2008? or 2012? You only tag the version you are using.

Comment: Also, if you are using any of those versions, 2005 and 2008 are **completely** unsupported, and 2012 only has 18~ months of extended support left.

Answer (score 0):

use lower() or upper()

```
SELECT SUM(metric), lower(name) 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY lower(name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wish to keep the raw data. Is there other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the collation to a case-sensitive collation and use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT SUM(metric), MIN(name COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN)
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try that~